# How to recognize google.appengine from PYTHONPATH in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

When I started using PyCharm, it does not recognize only `google.appengine` . It says `Unresolved references` .

I thought it automatically read my `PYTHONPATH` in launch.

My PYTHONPATH is below.

```
/Users/taichi/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/:/Users/taichi/myrepo/api/
```

[image: error]

I use `virtualenv` to set up the environment.

My project interpreter is this, but what is wrong?

[image]

Comment: Do you have App Engine support enabled in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Google App Engine**?

Comment: It worked, but still says `Cannot find reference 'appengine' in '__init__.py'` and `Unresolved reference 'ndb'` ...

Comment: Adding `/Users/taichi/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine` to the GAE config of PyCharm worked! Thank you!